# How to change order in multiple select2

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, jquery-select2

In my code I use a multiple select2 to select a value. the problem, however, is that you can not change the order in the select. can someone help me with that?

```
<select class="form-control col-10" id="questions" name="questions[]" multiple="multiple">
                    @foreach($tasks as $t)
                        @if(!$t->trashed() || in_array($t->id, $lesson->tasksId()))
                            <option value="{{$t->id}}" @if(in_array($t->id, $lesson->tasksId())) selected @endif>{{$t->vocabulary->native_text}}</option>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </select>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#questions').select2();
        $('#lessonLevelEdit').on('change', loadOtherTasks);
    });

    function loadOtherTasks() {
        const newVal = $('#lessonLevelEdit').val();
        $.get(`/api/tasks?level=${newVal}`, function(data) {
            // Reformat data to select2 structure
            const dataReformat = data.map(item => {
                return {
                    'id': item.id,
                    'text': item.vocabulary_nt
                }
            });
            // Remove old options (previous level)
            $('#questions option').remove();

            $('#questions').select2({
                data:dataReformat
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please add input and expected output

Comment: when I choose 3 values, I want to change the order by dragging the values.

Comment: Dragging where?

Comment: I have found this example: https://codepen.io/martinsanne/pen/zdZLrd , I only have no idea how to apply it in my code

Comment: You can include your code into that link fork it and then send link here

Comment: https://codepen.io/Meerman2001/pen/mQXbwZ this one works online, but not in my application